# How to define n symbolic variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to define n symbolic variables in Matlab. For example, if the user enters `n=3` then compiler defines `x1`, `x2`, `x3` as symbolic variables (the range of `n` is unlimited). How can I do this by `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the same advice holds for symbolic variables as for regular variables:

If you can prevent it, don't create numbered variables. Use a vector instead.

I cannot try it myself, but I believe `doc syms` will lead you to this:

```
A = sym('A',dim) %creates a vector or a matrix of symbolic variables.
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a loop.

```
N = input('How many variables? ');
strArray = [ repmat('x',N,1) dec2base(1:N,10) repmat(' ',N,1)]; % create strings
strArray = strvcat(regexprep(mat2cell(strArray, ...
  ones(1,size(strArray,1)), size(strArray,2)),'x0+','x')).'; % remove heading 0's
str = ['syms ' strArray(:).']; % string to be avaluated
eval(str)
```

For example, inputing "11", the string

```
syms x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9  x10 x11
```

is built and evaluated, which creates the 11 symbolic variables,

Answer (score 0):

Creating a vector as @DennisJaheruddin shows is really the standard way, but if you really need separate variables:

```
for i = 1:10
    x = sprintf('x%d',i);
    assignin('caller',x,sym(x));
end
```

Or this will do it in one line:

```
arrayfun(@(n)assignin('caller',sprintf('x%d',n),sym(sprintf('x%d',n))),1:10)
```